# Android file changes server - client

Tags: android, file

Right now I'm working on an app that should download a file from the internet. However, it would be very bad if it would download it every time when the app starts. I tried to get the size through an UrlConnection and of the local file with an InputStream, but for some reason the sizes are completely different (4x the size).

So I can't check it like that. What would be another easy way to check the file from the server? It has to be both fast and light on Client and Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could version the file on both the server and client and check the version before downloading.